# SVG image not loading on smartphones unless cached

Tags: android, html, ios, svg

I have a [header SVG image](https://canlogger1000.csselectronics.com/img/CAN-bus-data-loggers-css-electronics-canedge-clx000.svg) on my website landing page, https://www.csselectronics.com/.

This header image displays correctly on all desktop browser I've tested. However, I've recently found that it sometimes does not display at all when using a smartphone (e.g. iPhone 10, iPhone 11, Android phones).

The image simply is not loaded, though if a manual refresh is done on the page it seems to load correctly. The non-loading can then be re-triggered by clearing the image cache on the phone.

Any idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: `does not display at all when using a smartphone` What do you mean exactly? When using a browser on a smartphone who tries to display the landing page? Or the svg url?

Comment: `Log data to 8-32 GB SD` 32 GB is enough?

Comment: If a user tries to access our landing page (the link in my outline), the header image does not display on some Android phones and iPhones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the result of using negative margins on the image div container.